# ListPreference.setSummary will take "10 Percent" but crashes on "10%"

Tags: android, listpreference

I'm writing an android app with a ListPreference on a preferences screen that allows the user to choose a value from 10%, 20%, 30% ... 100%.

After the user changes the value (in `OnPreferenceChangeListener.onPreferenceChange()`) when I try to change the ListPreference's summary to the chosen value (`ListPreference.setsummary(<string>)`), I found that the app crashes when `<string>` ends in "%" but not when it ends in " Percent".

Has anyone ever seen this?  Do you know why it happens?  Is there a workaround that allows me to use "%"?

Comment: BTW, it took me a couple of hours to diagnose this issue.  Not fun.

Comment: Please post relevant code and the stacktrace.

Answer (score 13):

Got the same issue on android 4.0.4. Seems it's android bug.

My solution is to use Unicode symbol **fullwidth percent sign (U+FF05)** instead of **percent sign**. Sample data for ListPreference:

```
<string-array name="widget_transparency_title">
    <item>0\uff05 - не прозрачный</item>
    <item>25\uff05 прозрачности</item>
    <item>50\uff05 прозрачности</item>
    <item>75\uff05 прозрачности</item>
    <item>100\uff05 - прозрачный</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can answer the part of the question that relates to "Do you know why it happens?", but @Sash0k has already supplied a definitive workaround.

It happens because the android `ListPreference` class `getSummary()` method attempts to return a formatted string and thinks the '%' character is a precursor to some formatting.

For info the exception raised is `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException`.

An alternative workaround would be to just use "%%", though this isn't satisfactory if you are using the same string-array items to display the preference list (as the list will show the double %!)